# Geospatial Indexing with Redis & Sinatra for a Facebook App

Tags: indexing, geolocation, geospatial, redis, sunspot

I'm rebuilding [Lovers on Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/loversapp) with Sinatra & Redis, and I want:

- **Set operations** for managing requests & relationships between users
- **Geospatial indexing** to display nearby app users

#### Current Redis Implementation

Each user has two Redis ordered sets (`reqSent` & `reqRecv`) that store uids. The `SCORE` that we order the requests by is the `time` (UNIX timestamp) the request was made. I am using ordered sets instead of lists because a user may only make The request type (rid) is encoded as a number and prepended to the uid. (rid|uid) E.g., for the user with uid=100, we might have:

```
100:reqSent => ["1|123", "2|123", "2|134"]  # format: ["rid|tid"]
100:reqRecv => ["3|343", "5|142", "4|2224"] # format: ["rid|uid"]
```

[MongoDB supports geospatial indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) natively, so I'm thinking of switching to that.

Otherwise, how should I implement geospatial indexing with Redis? Should I do it with [Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/) (localsolr)? Apparently, you can use [Sunspot with Redis](http://masonoise.wordpress.com/2010/02/06/using-sunspot-for-free-text-search-with-redis/).

Answer (score 7):

I like to avoid multiple platforms and have implemented something similar using redis. Geospatial indexing isn't all that different to indexing anything else in redis. You just need a function to convert lat/long to a single number covering an appropriate area, then you use than number as the key to a set containing all users in that area. If you chose the area right, retrieving that set and possibly some of its neighbours should get you an appropriate number of users to run actual distance calculations on for final filtering/sorting.

The general case of geospatial queries would be quite hard to implement, but you don't need it and redis is the wrong platform for ad hoc queries anyway.

Comment: What is "a function to convert lat/long to a single number covering an appropriate area"?  You make it sound trivial but it's not.  Also, you need to be careful because an approximation that is performant when you have 1000 users might not be when you have 1000000.

Comment: The function is both trivial and arbitrary - (lat+90)*180+long will gives you a single number for everything within 1 degree, and you can get whatever precision you want by adding some constants. Performance isn't an issue if you choose the precision right - the initial query gets you a number of records that is reasonable to run the full calculation on.

Comment: hi Tom Clarkson, I talked about that yesturday to a guy who use monDB for geoindexing, did u finaly used redis for that task ? sounds like a great idea for me.

Comment: "The function is both trivial and arbitrary - (lat+90)*180+long " : sounds likes I will be ok to check if point is close on longitude, but not on lat as you multiply it by 180. maybe it can be done with usign zsort with 2 sorted sets : 1 for lat, 1 for long.

Comment: That isn't used directly for determining distance between points, just an initial step that gets you a reasonable number of records to check properly - i.e if a point is in block x, nearby means x-180/x/x+180 so you only need to search in 3 blocks instead of 360.

Comment: for geoindexing, you can look at geohash (php implementation here : https://github.com/asonge/php-geohash)

Comment: Wonderful! Your function solves a massive problem I have with searching for nearest points on a map. But where exactly a constant must be added to adjust the precision? I tried different variations but couldn't just expand the area of the box. Thanks!

Comment: @TomClarkson I would add that the list of records to be further checked should be comprised of "adjacent" blocks as well. The problem with the naive approach is that you could be near the edge of a "block", therefore ignoring very close points in a neighboring block.

As a solution to that, one could read records for 9 blocks (Moore neighborhood), or conversely, write records to 9 blocks. Then process further for properly checking.

Answer (score 4):

Implementing geospatial indexing in Redis sounds prohibitively time consuming if you think MongoDB is a valid option. Mongo is fast and very nice to work with. If the majority of the queries will be against the geospatial index there is no reason not to use Mongo, in my opinion.

I often find myself using both Mongo and Redis in the same project. They both have very useful properties, and some use cases work really well in Mongo, and some in Redis. However, the converse is also true, some things are really, really hard to get right in Redis, and other things aren't practically possible in Mongo. Geospatial indexes is an example of the former and set operations an example of the latter.

Also, without knowing very much about Sunspot, would it really use Redis? Doesn't it use Solr, which uses the filesystem for storage? It doesn't sound to me like you could get Redis in there, and unless I'm completely wrong I would say that you should definitely go with MongoDB.