# What should I store in Firestore so that I can fetch data on the basis of details get from autocomplete place api?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-places-api

I am taking input from user to get place detail by using autocomplete `place api` offered by Google.

Now I want to get each document from Firestore which belongs to this place. So to do this what approach should I follow? What should I store in documents so I can easily find it out.

**My approach**

```
   myShopsCollection
           shopDoc1
              city:"xyz"
              arrayId:[placeId1,PlaceId2,PlaceId3]
           shopDoc2
                  ....
```

Now I get placeId `PID` from autocomplete api 
my query become like this

```
db.collection(myShopsCollection').where('arrayId','array-contains',PID)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I thought I should store placeIds in array to in each document then get placeId from Place api and get documents if array contains this placeId

Comment: But problem is that onle place can have multiple placeId

Comment: Can you sketch what you have in mind?

Comment: @ AlexMamo I have updated my question please check it out

Comment: You should store location lat-long in GeoPoint data type and filter the data on the basis of distance.

Comment: Your approach looks feasible to me. What is the issue?

Comment: @alexaMamo problem is that one place can have multiple placeId.so if placeId got from autocomplete api may have differ from which i have stored in shopDoc for same place

Comment: @Ishant If you search some thing in big area like whole delhi and shopDoc store Geopoint for their location( belongs to delhi) then how you calculate distance ?

Comment: Geoqueries are not natively implement in Firestore yet, but some developers have implemented their own "nearby queries" on top of it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630507/how-to-run-a-geo-nearby-query-with-firestore,  my video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q and this shorter tutorial: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/geolocation-query-in-firestore-realtime/