# Get users from certain radius by latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, location

I've locations coordinates in Firebase Firestore for each user with latitude and longitude. I want to query only users by their coordinates in certain radius. For example, 50km. How this can be done if I know only latitude and longitude for each user?

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66363250/2781088

Comment: if my answer helped you, it would be appreciated to vote it up or check it as a correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 6.0, longitude: 6.0)
    
    let coordinate1 = CLLocation(latitude: 6.1, longitude: 6.1)
    let coordinate2 = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 3.0)
    let coordinate3 = CLLocation(latitude: 7.0, longitude: 3.0)
    
    let coordinatesArray = [coordinate1, coordinate2, coordinate3]
    
    for coordinate in coordinatesArray {
        if userLocation.distance(from: coordinate) < 50000 {
            print("Inside 50 km")
        }
    }
```

Note that `distance(from:)` method is measured in meters, thats why I am checking if it is inside `50000m(50km)`. Print statement should be executed for coordinate1 because it is `15.6 km` away.

Comment: Note that OP wants all users within a certain radius, maybe you should adjust your answer for that.

Comment: yeah, i have edited