# when i try retrieve snapshot from firebase by flutter does not retrieve any thing

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, location

I found this website [How to run a geo "nearby" query with firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630507/how-to-run-a-geo-nearby-query-with-firestore) for find nearby location from my current location
when try write swift code to dart like in below it does not retrieve data, please till me what the problem ?

```
void getDocumentNearBy( double latitude, double longitude , double distance) {

   ~1 mile of lat and lon in degrees
   var lat = 0.0144927536231884;
   var lon = 0.0181818181818182;

var lowerLat = latitude - (lat * distance);
var lowerLon = longitude - (lon * distance);

var greaterLat = latitude + (lat * distance);
var greaterLon = longitude + (lon * distance);

var lesserGeopoint = GeoPoint(lowerLat, lowerLon);
var greaterGeopoint = GeoPoint(greaterLat, greaterLon);


 var docRef = firestore.collection("Coupons");
  var query = docRef.where("Coupons", isGreaterThan: lesserGeopoint).where("Coupons",  isLessThan: greaterGeopoint);



query.snapshots();
builder: (BuildContext context,
AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
if (snapshot.hasData) {
   print(query);
 }else {
       print("there is an error");

  }

  };





void run() {
  Get all locations within 10 miles of Google Headquarters
  getDocumentNearBy(37.422000,  -122.084057,10);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a proper code snippet on how you used `query.snapshots()`. What's the widget you are using in the `builder` line?

Comment: I am a beginner in language and do not understood what you said, please can you explain

Comment: As @rickimaru suggested please provide the necessary information required for troubleshooting. The link you have provided has a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q) that describes the whole process in details. Did you watch the video?