# Query Google Firestore database by custom object fields

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I've got the following Google Firestore database structure:
[image]

Is there a way to query by a range of each - latitude and longitude? For example I want to get all users which have `location.lat` and `location.lng` in the range of: `51.400` to `52.000` and `-0.100` to `-0.300`. Can anyone please help me figure out the query needed to do that?

I hope this question makes any sense. Any help appreciated.

Edit: I am not using a 'Geographical point' data type. I am using a custom object with 2 float numbers and want to do a simple number compare. The thing is that I do not know (and cannot find) a way how to build my query.

Comment: What you're describing is known as a geoquery, and Firestore doesn't support them yet. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607760/how-to-query-closest-geopoints-in-a-collection-in-firebase-cloud-firestore/46608540#46608540

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query closest GeoPoints in a collection in Firebase Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607760/how-to-query-closest-geopoints-in-a-collection-in-firebase-cloud-firestore)

Comment: Appreciate your comment Frank, but I was aware of that. A 'location' field in my case is a custom object which stores two numbers. I want to do a simple '>' or '<' compare between two numbers.

Answer (score 13):

This much should be possible

```
userRef.where('location.lat', '>=', 51.400).where('location.lat', '<=', 52.000);
```

Though I don't think you can chain more `.where` on it if it's not on the same field.

You could try to do a similar query for `location.lng` beneath it and then compare and match the users from both queries. Or check if the `location.lng` is in the desired range in your code and filter out those users. In any case you'll end up getting more results from the database than preferred and then discarding some.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I guess that's the way I am going to do it. 2 queries and then take matching results from both. Google Firebase is getting more and more disappointing with every issue I face.

Comment: I feel the same way about Firestore. On the surface it's been a huge improvement over Firebase, but if you want to perform more complicated queries in a deeply nested database it become a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a solution for this is to have a cloud function that adds a `lat_range` and a `lon_range` field to each document as it comes into Firebase? You'll need to have predefined ranges though - so you know what you can query.