# Get nearest users within a circle by current location node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation

I'm explaining with an example to achieve my result.

I have a users table. Each user has their location with latitude and longitude on the database. I'm using firebase database. So the DB looks like:

```
users {
  user-id{
     location{
        latitude
        longitude
     }
  }
}
```

I need to find users within a circle using my current location.

I've looked into [geolib](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib) and found a method [isPointInCircle](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib#geolibispointincircleobject-latlng-object-center-integer-radius) . But using this, we need to iterate users data and needs to call this method on each loop. I need to avoid this multiple calls and achieve with only one method call like:

```
findNearestUsers(currentLocation,userLocations);
```

The result should be an array having nearest locations. How can I do this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/geofire

Comment: yes, I've looked into this one. But I cannot find any logic about my requirement

Comment: As a side note, the new Firestore should implement geo queries eventually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoFire is the only way to query the Firebase Realtime Database based on proximity to a specific point, without having to download all data and filtering client side.

With GeoFire you [create a `GeoQuery` for a location and a maximum distance](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geoquery):

```
var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
  center: [10.38, 2.41],
  radius: 10.5
});
```

You then [attach handlers for items that fall within this range](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geoqueryoneventtype-callback):

```
var onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
  console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
});
```

There is no built-in functionality for finding a single, closest item. You could do that client-side based on the `distance` parameter in the callback. You'd still be retrieving more data than needed, but hopefully it'd be less than the entire database.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thank you for your reply. Let me do with this

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to index and query the Firebase realtime database without getting the whole dataset and process locally.

I suggest switching to the new released beta Cloud Firestore instead which even has a geopoint as a data type and better support for sql-like "where queries".
[Cloud Firestore queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I cannot try on my current project. Because almost done using firebase. I would try on my next project. Instead of the database can you suggest anything for the geolocation functionality?

Comment: While Firestore supports geo-data, it does [not currently support geo-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46608540). There **is** a fine way to accomplish the same on the Firebase Realtime Database, it's a library called GeoFire. If you need geo-query support today today, that is the [recommended route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554998).