# Error installing Geofirestore - Could not find remote branch 1.1.0 to clone

Tags: terminal, cocoapods, geofire

I'll be honest my knowledge of Terminal is little to none.  I normally just run pod install and they work, however, I have the below error on installing the pod 'Geofirestore'

I am getting the directory of my Xcode project in the terminal and calling pod install

[image: Terminal Output Error]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You shoul use latest library of Geofirestore i.e. 1.2.0
In Pod file,
pod "GeoFire", "~> 3.0.0"
pod "Geofirestore", "~> 1.2.0"

Hope it helps.